# TortoiseSVN CLI tools stop working after update

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

The command line tools that install with the TortoiseSVN installer are not working for me. They worked in 1.7.x, but when I upgraded from 1.7.x to 1.7.11 they stopped working. The Windows Explorer GUI works fine. Updating, checking in, etc, work nicely from the GUI. But when I try to use the command line, it says

> the path '.' appears to be subversion 1.7 or greater working copy.

It also displays a message that I may need to update the Subversion client to the working copy. I uninstalled TortoiseSVN completely and reinstalled it with the most recent version and the command line tools still don't work. What can I do to fix this issue?

Comment: Is that exact error message, "the path seems to be subversion 1.7 or greater"?

Comment: updated the exact message.

Comment: What's the result of `svn --version`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are not executing the `svn` command that's bundled with TortoiseSVN. To make sure, you can use the full path, e.g.:

```
"%programfiles%\TortoiseSVN\bin\svn" status
```

Check your system's `PATH` variable:

```
echo %PATH%
```

There's possibly some other directory with SVN binaries.

Comment: Strange, we had the correct paths and everything. We removed the path and then re-added the same exact path... and it worked. Windows...